# Whats wrong with my fish?

Tags: health, goldfish

Not sure what’s wrong with my fish. Got this fish about 3 years ago. Always been fine, in a small tank. Moved him in to a 50 gallon tank, and randomly( few months in ) grows a big ball on his head looks weird looks like 50 small little bubbles. Not sure what’s wrong I feed him pebbles and used to feed him flakes I change/clean tank every few ( 2-3 ) months ( water always looks good ) can anyone help me out? Not sure if he’s in danger or pain. ( I tried to link a picture but didn’t let me)

Comment: If you struggle with photo uploads, make sure that you are not exceeding the size limit - aim for 2MB or less.

Comment: please add a bit more information about your tank,is it heated,do you have any filtration,what temperature do you keep in your tank.and please post the result of your last watertest,ammonia-nitrite-ph.

Comment: Maybe you can also give some information what kind of fish it is...

Comment: @Allerleirauh it’s a Gold fish.

Comment: @trondhansen honestly. I’m not even sure. I had just used water from my house. Maybe that’s the issue he used to have clean water like those water things that fill up ur gallons, clean water. Then I randomly switched him to water from well water, but the well water is in good condition, maybe he wasn’t used to it. I was using a filter for about a month but it randomly stopped working so I never cared to fix it or get a new one. I’m not the best owner cause I’m not that informed on sertian things. But I always make sure to my fishes water is clean and feed him

Comment: @Spliqbtw for the fish's sake, please don't use tap water in your tank unless you have a proper dechlorinator.

Answer (score -1):

Your fish is inbred
[image: Ranchu Goldfish]

From the description you're giving, I suspect your fish is a Ranchu goldfish, a breed of goldfish known for it's bumpy head produced by extensive selective breeding.

I believe the specific term is lymphosystist, a genetic disorder characterized by an extremely lumpy head, present in Ranchu breeds.

How do you get lymphosystist? **your family tree must be a straight line**, or, in other words, inbred as hell.

It may affect your fish's ability to breathe and may make him more susceptible to infections

Comment: welcome to pets.SE! Please give a source where your knowledge comes from.

Comment: only vague memory, but from YouTuber AVNJ, an Ichthyologist from New jersey + random fish website rabbit holes, I'm sorry if this information is not valid enough

Comment: Because we handle living beings here, sources are crutial to research further and evaluate the information. Maybe you can have a quick search and link a relevant video of the channel? Minimum the picture you have somewhere from in short history...

Comment: @Allerleirauh alright, will get on that soon